# Set locale on momentJS won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs

I've installed momentJS on ionic/angular using bower - and it works fine. Except for changing locale to 'fr' or 'da'. The files are available in the locales-folder, but the following code still echoes in english   :(

```
moment.locale('fr');
var NowMoment = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do");
console.log(NowMoment);
```

It's written in my directive/link function. Should I do anything different ?

Thanx
Ask

Comment: Did you load/include the lang file for `fr`?

Comment: of course - including the language file helps   ;)   thanx - feel free to post as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

moment.js itself does not load any language files. So as long as you do not use `moment+locales.js` (which would contain all locals) you will either need to include the additional language data  with your `moment.js` or you need to load it separate.

So either something like this:

```
<script src="/js/moment+fr.js"></script>
```

Or this that way:

```
<script src="/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/js/locale/fr.js"></script>
```

If you only use `fr` then you would not need to call `moment.locale('fr');` in this particular case, because the last loaded *local* will be the active one.